# Disable mouse for a certain domain in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'd like be able to disable the mouse in Chrome on `gmail.com` in order to force myself to use the [Gmail keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594) instead. Is this possible, perhaps with a Chrome extension?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on Windows, here is a solution that uses the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

You would use a AutoHotkey script such as:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2            ; match string anywhere in title
#IfWinActive, gmail.com         ; if the active window contains "gmail.com"
LButton::return                 ; disable all mouse buttons
RButton::return
MButton::return
XButton1::return
XButton2::return
^LButton::Send {Click}          ; control-clicks are passed as clicks (contingency)
^RButton::Send {Click Right}
```

This script will disable (almost) all possible clicks while the currently active
window contains "gmail.com" in its title. For security, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key
will enable left and right clicks, as contingency just in case.

After installing AutoHotKey, put the script in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ***[User Javascript and CSS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld?hl=en)*** extension to add any custom CSS to any website, for your case, install the extension, enable it then open Gmail, and click the extension icon and click "Add New", a new tab will open, in the right side (which is the CSS side) write the following CSS"

```
* {
    cursor: none !important;
}
```

Click "Save" at the top right corner, close the tab and then just refresh the Gmail page and it should work.